# Address JS ES6 Map in arrow functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

In [Observable](https://observablehq.com/@kalmdown/network-issues) I have a Map called **dataByHub**, currently looks like:

```
"ST" => Array(19) [Object, Object, Object ...]
"FING" => Array(27) [Object, Object, Object ...]
```

I am trying to iterate over the key (Are ST, FING keys? Not sure of nomenclature...)

```
d3.select("#hubs").selectAll(".hub")
    .data(dataByHub) 
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "hub")
    .attr("id", (d,i) => d[i])
```

I want:

```
<g class="hub" id="ST"></g>
<g class="hub" id="FING"></g>
```

The result I get is:

```
<g class="hub" id="ST"></g>
<g class="hub" id="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"></g>
```

How do I get the result I want?

Bonus: How do I address the Objects in a key of the Map in a => to iterate over them and use the values of the objects?

Comment: You should ask your bonus question as a new question

Comment: I second the comment above.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68077965/1533309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the key (you were right, that's the correct nomenclature) of each key-value pair in the Map. Therefore, you just need to use the index `0` for each entry (which is the datum, `d`) for getting its key:

```
.attr("id", d => d[0]);
```

Here is the demo:.

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const dataByHub = new Map();
dataByHub.set("ST", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
dataByHub.set("FING", [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(dataByHub)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "hub")
  .attr("id", d => d[0]);
var mySVG = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg.node());
console.log(mySVG)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

As an additional explanation, it's worth mentioning that D3 `data` method uses `Array.from` internally for Maps, Sets and Strings. That's why each of your datum (`d`) is an array, with the original Map key as the element at index `0` and the original Map value as the element at index `1`:

```js
const dataByHub = new Map();
dataByHub.set("ST", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
dataByHub.set("FING", [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
console.log(Array.from(dataByHub))
```

It's also worth mentioning that since v6 (we're in v7 now) D3 accepts iterables, like Maps and Sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dataByHub.keys()` to set the `id` of the `g` elements:

```js
const data = [
  {hub: "ST", Xs: [1, 2]},
  {hub: "FING", Xs: [2, 3]},
  {hub: "ST", Xs: [3, 4]},
  {hub: "FING", Xs: [4, 5]},
  {hub: "ST", Xs: [5, 6]},
  {hub: "FING", Xs: [6, 7]},
  {hub: "ST", Xs: [7, 8]},
];

const dataByHub = d3.group(data, d => d.hub);

const svg = d3.select("svg");

const hubs = svg.selectAll(".hubs")
  .data(dataByHub.keys())
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "hub")
  .attr("id", d => d)

hubs.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 160)
  .attr("height", 140)
  .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(${(i * 180) + 20}, 20)`);
  
hubs.append("text")
  .text(d => `I am rect in ${d} <g>`)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => (i * 180) + 25)
  .attr("y", 90)
  .attr("fill", "blue");
```

```css
svg {
  background: lightblue;
}

g.hub rect {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=380 height=180></svg>
```

Comment: In Observable using D3@6  "d3.group(data, d => d.hub)" returns a Map like I show in my example above. And since Maps are part of future releases I want to know how to use them properly, vs converting things to arrays.