# D3@6 Generic direction on addressing Map data structures in arrow functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

Have an [Observable](https://observablehq.com/@kalmdown/network-issues) using D3 v6 and am starting to use the Map data structure. While it seems array-based I am having difficulty translating how to get to different parts of maps in arrow functions.

I have a data set shaped:

```
dataByHub = Map(2) {
  "ST" => Array(19) [Object, Object, Object... ]
  "FING" => Array(27) [Object, Object, Object ...]
```

A **log** of the *data* going into the function to generate the path looks like:

```
data 
Pn {_groups: Array(2), _parents: Array(2)}
_groups: (2) [Array(19), Array(27)]
_parents: (2) [g#ST.hub, g#FING.hub]
__proto__: Object
```

...and, for each hub (_parents which determines my y_hub), I want to iterate over the appropriate Array (_group) and pass in the sets of Xs to a function to create a path. The result should be a line with variable length spaces and dashes representing disconnection events.

What I have...

The D3 portion looks like, where I want to attach the Xs from a hub to a path:

```
  d3.select("#hubs").selectAll(".hub")
    .data(dataByHub) 
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "hub")
    .attr("id", d => d[0])
    .selectAll("path")
    .data((d,i) => d[1])
    .join("path")
      .call(log,"data")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("d", (d,i) => segment(d.Xs,i))
```

Which uses segment() to generate the path:

```
function segment(data, hub) {
  const p = d3.path();
  console.log("segment", data); //data.Xs[0]
  const y_hub = hub * 100;
  p.moveTo(data.Xs[0],y_hub);
  p.lineTo(data.Xs[1],y_hub);
  p.closePath();
  // console.log("p", p);
  return p.toString();
}
```

I have tried different setups for the .data for the path but either get **undefined** or an individual pair of Xs's instead of a series of them.

Comment: Do you want to pass a single array of datetime pairs e.g. `[[datetime1, datetime2], [datetime1, datetime2], [datetime1, datetime2]...]` ? Or, do you want to pass a single pair `i` times, where `i` is the number of array items grouped in `dataByHub` for that hub?

Comment: THe single, I think. Was thinking that the appropriate thing to do was iterate over the pairs in the path "d" statement...send data.`ST'[0].Xs[0], data.`ST'[0].Xs[1], data.`ST'[1].Xs[0], data.`ST'[1].Xs[1], data.`ST'[2].Xs[0], data.`ST'[2].Xs[1]...If I pass in the whole array then I would restructure segment()..and rename it to events().

Comment: In that last `.attr(...)` the variable `d` should be an object from your original array e.g. `{Hub: "FING", Xs: [datetime, datetime]}` and `i` is the index of that object in the array of objects which is the value in the Map. So `.data((d, i) => d[1]` is correct if you want those objects one by one. If you want the *entire* array as a datum then use `.data((d, i) => [d[1]]` (note the outer brackets). If you don't want `Xs[0]` in your `segment` function, and want an array like `[[datetime, datetime], [datetime, datetime]... etc]` then you need 2nd approach. It's not clear to me in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@Robin Mackenzie's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765395/robin-mackenzie) question about passing an array or individual pair I refactored the function to accept the array.

So the call became:

```
.attr("d", (d,i) => events(d[1]) )
```

However, the important part of the solution was how to get to the elements of the Map. The missing piece was the index into the array after "data" before ".Xs"

```
function events(data) {
  const p = d3.path();
  const y_hub = yScale(data[0].Hub);
  for (var n=0; n < data.length; n++) {
    p.moveTo(xScale(data[n].Xs[0]),y_hub);
    p.lineTo(xScale(data[n].Xs[1]),y_hub);
    }
  p.closePath();
  return p.toString();
}
```

Thanks to my friend Alex Carroll for additional help on Maps.